# URL Scheme, Open the application when url/link is tapped without modifying the link. IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

what my app currently has is when user tapped the link it opens the app and it works perfectly but my problem is I add something to the prefix of my url

this is the original url to be catch in my app

`www.mywebsiteurl.com?variable=catchthisvalue`

I achieved this by using `URL Schemes` and this is the prefix I added to my link `myappname://` and the link become this

`myappname://www.mywebsiteurl.com?variable=catchthisvalue`

to get the original link I added this code to my appDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        let cleanString = url.absoluteString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("myappname://", withString: "")
        BaseURL.shared.isSet = String(cleanString)
        return true
    }
```

the `cleanString` is the original url I saved it to NSUserDefaults, this process is perfectly working, but my client don't want to change the url

my question is can I open my app without adding prefix or anything in original url?

Comment: Read about [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

Comment: @rmaddy I will, thank you for the lead!